# Geometry showing through when X-ray is off

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

I've messed up with the rendering/clipping distance or something, because now geometry is showing through solid faces in edit mode at a relatively close distance to the object, which was not the case before:

[image]
[image]

And probably related to this issue, the intersection between two volumes is being rendered in the viewport as jagged edges:

[image]

Is there a slider somewhere that fixes this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to turn down the clipping distance in "N-panel > View > View > [Clip] End".